# How to find all instances of list values(ex: [1,2,3]) in a file at a specific index

Tags: python

I want to find out a list of elements in a file at a specific index.

For ex, below are the contents of the file "temp.txt"

```
line_0 1
line_1 2
line_2 3
line_3 4
line_4 1
line_5 1
line_6 2
line_7 1
line_8 2
line_9 3
line_10 4
```

Now, I need to find out the list of values [1,2,3] occurring in sequence at column 2 of each line in above file.

Output should look like below:

```
line_2 3
line_9 3
```

I have tried the below logic, but it some how not working ;(

```
   inf = open("temp.txt", "rt")
   count = 0
   pos = 0
   ListSeq = ["1","2","3"]
   for line_no, line in enumerate(inf):
      arr = line.split()
      if len(arr) > 1:
         if count == 1 :
            pos = line_no
         if ListSeq[count] == arr[1] :
            count += 1
         elif count > 0 :
            inf.seek(pos)
            line_no = pos
            count = 0
         else :
            count = 0            
      if count >= 3 :
         print(line)
         count = 0
```

Can somebody help me in finding the issue with above code? or even a different logic which will give a correct output is also fine.

Comment: *occurring in sequence at index 2 of each line* - can you elaborate?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest : I have edited the question, I mean column-2, not index-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is flawed. Most prominent bug: trying to `seek` in a text file using line number is never going to work: you have to use byte offset for that. Even if you did that, it would be wrong because you're iterating on the lines, so you shouldn't attempt to change file pointer while doing that.

My approach:

The idea is to "transpose" your file to work with vertical vectors, find the sequence in the 2nd vertical vector, and use the found index to extract data on the first vertical vector.

`split` lines to get text & number, zip the results to get 2 vectors: 1 of numbers 1 of text.

At this point, one list contains `["line_0","line_1",...]` and the other one contains `["1","2","3","4",...]`

Find the indexes of the sequence in the number list, and print the couple txt/number when found.

code:

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    sequence = ('1','2','3')
    txt,nums = list(zip(*(l.split()[:2] for l in f)))  # [:2] in case there are more columns
    for i in range(len(nums)-len(sequence)+1):
        if nums[i:i+len(sequence)]==sequence:
            print("{} {}".format(txt[i+2],nums[i+2]))
```

result:

```
line_2 3
line_9 3
```

last `for` loop can be replaced by a list comprehension to generate the tuples:

```
result = [(txt[i+2],nums[i+2]) for i in range(len(nums)-len(sequence)) if nums[i:i+len(sequence)]==sequence ]
```

result:

```
[('line_2', '3'), ('line_9', '3')]
```

Comment: This is giving the intended output. But I am feeling little difficulty in understanding the logic, as I am a beginner to Python. I will look for a simpler solutions(time is not a constraint for me) before accepting this answer.
-Thanks

Comment: I think, this will work only if the number of columns is unique through-out the file. Correct?
How to make this work even if the number of columns are different in each line, provided each line contains minimum 2 columns.

Comment: Also, the above code is not working, if the sequence and the file contains exactly the same number of elements.

Comment: @programmerDaemon: taken care of, added a +1, you were right. And fixed the thing with more than 2 columns. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing for any sequence and any column.

```py
sequence = ['1','2','3']
col = 1

with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
    idx = 0
    for _i, line in enumerate(infile):
        if line.strip().split()[col] == sequence[idx]:
            if idx == len(sequence)-1:
                print(line)
                idx = 0
            else:
                idx += 1
        else:
            idx = 0
```

Comment: int() may raise an exception

Comment: This will not give the output which I am looking for, Please see the output format mentioned in the post.
I have to find sequence of [1,2,3] in the second column of each line, and print the index of any of the element if the sequence is found.

Comment: @programmerDaemon I reread your question and modified my code accordingly, only thing unclear to me is the output format you are looking for: you want to print the _index_ or the whole line?

Comment: Actually the output format does not matter for me, It is okay to print the whole line, or simply the line number. My intention is to find all occurrences of the sequence, and my original use case has some other operations to do, once the sequence is found.

Comment: Build is failing with below error:

for i, line in enumerate(lines_gen):
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @programmerDaemon Sorry, wanted to go faster without testing. My latest edit seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @MattF. Not working for the sequence = ['1','2','4']

Comment: @programmerDaemon Forgot to paste last 2 lines of the program... sorry (:

Comment: Works fine now :)